# fb messenger bot always return empty json while verification of webhooks

Tags: node.js, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My node js bot is unable to verify the validation token for facebook messenger bot platform. I have done the webhook setup in the developer console correctly by following the given official documentation.
I have built a chatbot before so I can be pretty assured that I have correctly configured app console settings. Please check my following code and tell me if there is anything wrong with it.

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const VALIDATION_TOKEN = (process.env.MESSENGER_VALIDATION_TOKEN) ?
  (process.env.MESSENGER_VALIDATION_TOKEN) :
  'alex';


// Webhook route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  // console.log(req.query['hub.verify_token']);
  if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }
});

// Spin up the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

The console.log(req.query) returns an empty object and always the else part of the if-else executes and console prints : 
    "Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match."

Comment: Does your webhook route return nothing even when you try with curl command? Also, doesn't Facebook messenger allow only callback url with https? I am asking this since your code doesn't have https code. double-check your webhook setup again.

Comment: it returns { success : true }. and yes I am using heroku.

Comment: I actually copied the code from the examples given by facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible that you used "https://your_heroku_url/webhook" as your callback url when you setup webhook, but you are calling "https://your_heroku_url/" in your code. Try following code:

```
app.get('/webhook', function (req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }
});
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start

Comment: No I did the setup correctly. I am getting the user's messages on a post request.

Comment: hmm..how could you get a post request when webhook is not validated?